# Не получается передать значение переменной между методами и как запустить копию цикла в методе

Tags: java, методы

В общем есть у меня цикл фор, в цикле генератор случайных булевов истина или ложь, если истина то переменная i выводит ряд чисел в интервале. Так вот как можно определить этот самый цикл в метод чтобы я мог запустить множество его экземпляров где нибудь из кода при этом получая значение переменной i ?

```
for (int op = 0; op>0; op++) {
             boolean bo = random.nextBoolean();
             if (bo == true) {
                 for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                     try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println(i);

                }
            }

            else { 
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
```

То есть например у меня несколько выводов System.out.Println(), и каждый из них должен запускать новый экземпляр этого метода и получать разные значения переменной. Не обязательно на  Println() выводить это я так для примера можно drawText(), мне главное понять на этом примере. Спасибо!

Comment: У вас цикл бесконечный

Comment: Наоборот, безначальный

Comment: @Сергей Грушин да бесконечный мне так и надо

Comment: @СергейГрушин цикл `for (int op = 0; op > 0; op++)` выполнится ровно 0 раз. Поэтому его сложно называть бесконечным.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, используйте конструкцию бесконечного цикла такого вида, он лаконичнее и понятнее:

```
    while (true) {
        ... 
    }
```

---

Во-вторых, если я правильно понял Вашу задачу, можно попробовать делать так: создать отдельный класс с циклом в методе и для каждом классе экземпляра будет свой такой метод:

```
public class CyclerThread {
    public void startCycle() {
       //ТУТ ВАШ ЦИКЛ
    }
}
```

Использовать так:

```
new CyclerThread().startCycle();
new CyclerThread().startCycle();
new CyclerThread().startCycle();
```

Все три цикла будут работать одновременно и независимо друг от друга. Хотя, в идеале, каждый нужно запускать в отдельном потоке.

---

Чтобы получать значения `i`, можно передать или интерфейс, в который она будет передаваться, или метод в классе, в котором она будет браться.

Вариант 1:

```
public class CyclerThread {
    public interface Callback {
        void onValueChanged(int i);
    }

    public void startCycle(Callback callback) {
       ...

       if (ВАШЕ_УСЛОВИЕ) {
           callback.onValueChanged(i);
       }

       ...
    }
}
```

Вариант 2:

```
public class CyclerThread {
    private int i;

    ...

    public int getValue() {
        return i;
    }
}
```

---

Чтобы получить ответ, нужно передать анонимный класс в вызов метода:

```
    new CyclerThread().startCycle(new CyclerThread.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChanged(int i) {

        }
    });
```

Или, используя лямбды:

```
new CyclerThread().startCycle((i) -> ... );
```

Comment: Большое вам спасибо за ответ очень помогло, но я все же не пойму один момент, если я передаю значение через callback.onValueChanged(i); - то как мне его принять в другом классе? пробовал new CyclerThread().startCycle(int y); - int y но такая конструкция не сработала как не странно

Comment: @Jonathan, обновил ответ. Если ответ помог Вам, примите его, пожалуйста.

Comment: да конечно, еще раз большое вам спасибо.

Comment: пытался использовал лямбду int y=0;

            new CyclerThread().startCycle((i) -> i=y);

            canvas.drawText(""+y,100,100, paint); в итоге y=0, вроде лямбда так работает или я где-то ошибся?!

Comment: @Jonathan, эм... Не `i = y`, а `y = i`...

Comment: ой точно не заметил, но все равно "0" потому что просит Convert 'y' int final one element array

Comment: @Jonathan, а `i` к Вам приходит не "0"?

Comment: Отличный вопрос в принципе должно, но почему я просто не могу присвоить значение i переменной y, просит конвертировать в array?!

Comment: @Jonathan, а тут фишка видимости переменных. Если Вы в одном методе объявляете переменную и вложенный класс, тогда, чтобы использовать переменную — Вам нужно объявить ее `final`. IDEA предлагает внести ее в массив, потому что `final` массив можно модифицировать. Просто вынесете переменную из метода в класс. Да и читайте то, что Вам пишет IDEA (Android Studio), там все понятно объясняется.

Comment: да точно, вынес и ошибка пропала, ну если так то это значит что класс CyclerThread ничего не передает

Comment: @Jonathan, если класс ничего не передает — значит ошибка в коде и ее нужно решать отдельно. Может Вы что-то недопоняли и сделали не так, как надо. Выложите весь новый код, который у Вас получился в новом вопросе.

Comment: Здесь новый вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/625304/Почему-класс-не-передает-значение-переменной-через-лямбду

Answer (score 0):

У Вас описана некая логика. Эту логику нужно поместить в отдельный класс (некий `BooleanRandomGeneratorClassExample`).

И далее создавать объекты этого класса, которые или будут сразу печатать в консоль или будут возвращать на выходе коллекцию или массив с набором случайных значений.

Например BooleanRandomGeneratorClassExample.java

```
public class BooleanRandomGeneratorClassExample {

    public static List<Boolean> generateBooleanList(int size) {
        if (size < 1) {
            return null;
        }

        Random rand = new Random();
        List<Boolean> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            list.add(rand.nextBoolean());
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

Использование класса `BooleanRandomGeneratorClassExample`:

```
public class Application {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            List<Boolean> myList = BooleanRandomGeneratorClassExample.generateBooleanList(5);

            for (boolean bVal : myList) {
                System.out.println(bVal);
            }
       }
}
```

Вариант использования класса `BooleanRandomGeneratorClassExample` с бесконечностью:

```
    public class Application {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            List<Boolean> myList = null;

            while (1 == 1) {
                myList = BooleanRandomGeneratorClassExample.generateBooleanList(5);
                for (boolean bVal : myList) {
                    System.out.println(bVal);
                }
           }
       }
   }
```

Если нужна параллельная работа такого метода, то можно в классе `BooleanRandomGeneratorClassExample` реализовать метод `run()` и запускать класс `BooleanRandomGeneratorClassExample` в многопоточном режиме.

Comment: Спасибо выручил, ты написал что может возвращать массив с набором значений, а можно ли сделать так чтобы в каждом значении массива был новый экземпляр объекта?

Comment: Да, конечно.
Можно создавать массив или коллекцию объектов.
List<YourClassName> list = new ArrayList<>();
или YourClassName[] myArray = YourClassName[10];
Если в комменте непонятно, то напиши пример который нужен - я дополню свой ответ.
П.С. Лучшая благодарность - это +1 голос за ответ))

Comment: Нет, спасибо еще раз, все понятно. Разве что, как поставить +1 голос) я тут недавно)