# Почему класс не передает значение переменной через лямбду?

Tags: java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int y;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new MyView(this));
    }

    class MyView extends View {
        public MyView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }


        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            paint.setTextSize(20);
            canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);



            new CyclerThread().startCycle((i) -> y=i);


            canvas.drawText(""+ y,100,100, paint);
        }
    }
}
```

...................................................................

```
public class CyclerThread {
    public interface Callback {
        void onValueChanged(int i);
    }

        public void startCycle(Callback callback) {
            Random random = null;
            for (int op = 0; op>0; op++) {

                boolean bo = random.nextBoolean();
                if (bo == true) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(2000);
                            // any action
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        callback.onValueChanged(i);
                        // System.out.println(i);

                    }
                }

                else { 
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                        // any action
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: А что Вы хотите, собственно, получить от кода? Я немного не понял, что происходит в цикле.

Comment: Ну вообщем мне нужно менять значение в интервале, когда срабатывает булев `истинна`, то идет цикл от одного до пяти (i) с шагом две секунды, а если ложь то весь цикл целиком приостанавливается на пять секунд, мне нужно вывести много таких значений но естественно я не буду писать десятки таких циклов так как количество циклов будет определенно позже и оно всегда будет разным

Comment: Капнем еще глубже: зачем вам вообще это делать?) Может есть более хорошее решение?

Comment: вот мне и нужно запрашивать копию цикла и возвращать значение

Comment: к сожалению нет это самый простой способ решить мою задачу

Comment: Посмотрите ответ.

Comment: А какой ответ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Я вообще не уверен, что Ваш код работает. В нем слишком много противоречивых моментов. Сделайте все под другом, а не так, как Вы делаете сейчас.
2. Ваш код не работает, потому что значение `i` может вообще не присваиваться.

---

Попробуйте сделать так:

```
new CyclerThread().startCycle((i) -> canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(i), 100, 100, paint));
```

Хотя я считаю, что это ужасное решение.

---

Я не поленился и скопировал Ваш код в проект. Он попросту не работает.

IDEA ясно говорит, что цикл:

`for (int op = 0; op>0; op++)`

ВСЕГДА равен `false`. Измените его на `op >= 0` или используйте `while(true)`, что более предпочтительно.

---

Но Ваш код работать не будет, потому что класс `Random` равен `null`.

Comment: дело даже не в присваивании, вывел напрямую String.valueOf(i) результат 0, значит с класса ничего не передается

Comment: @Jonathan, сначала цикл передает 0, потом 1, потом 2 и т.д.

Comment: все верно. но в данный момент он ничего не передает

Comment: да точно цикл не рабочий, отредактировал  final Random random = new Random(); и (int op = 1; op>0; op++)  и цикл заработал но только в стандартном Ява компиляторе, только приложение андроид такой вариант грузит намертво

Comment: @Jonathan, мне кажется Вы немного не тем занимаетесь... Подтяните теорию. То, что Вы пытаетесь сделать — явно Вам не по силам. Найдите человека, который Вам подскажет или попросту купите нужную Вам программу :).

Comment: я думаю практическая часть не менее важна, но согласен теории у меня маловато, но все же я разобрался - оказалось что Канвас на котором я пытался вывести значения из цикла не делает отрисовку до тех пор пока цикл не завершится, а так как цикл бесконечный то и отрисовки неведать))